# How to find the TextRange of the Nth word in a WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Lets say I have a RichTextBox (WPF) of 1000 words (English). Some words will be Bold, Underlined, Italic, and of different FontSizes. In other words, there are many element tags embedded within the FlowDocument.

Without knowing what the word is, how can I completely select the 13th word -- and only the 13th word, even if it has embedded element tags (say some characters are Bold, or Underlined, etc.)?

(I have not found any solution to this with Google and I am still finding the RichTextBox a rather difficult control to use).

Example: "This is a test." 
Given: 3
Result: The TextRange of the word "test".

Any suggestions or ideas will be most appreciated.

TIA

Edit. It seems a loop will be needed :(.  Anyway, this blog post was most helpful in answering this problem:[Navigate Words in RichTextBox](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/prajakta/2006/11/01/navigate-words-in-richtextbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you mean by embaded element tags, I gave it a try and here is how I did it :

```
string a = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, 
rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
var b = a.Split(' ');
string On13th = b[12];
```

Let me know if I am not clear or you intended to achieve something else.

Comment: By embeded, I mean where the flowdocument has text like ...This i<Underline>s</Underline> a <Bold>te</Bold>st.  Does the "Text" property remove everything but the text string? Once finding b[12] how can this be converted back to a TextPointer?  Ultimately, I need the TextRange of the 13th word, not the word itself. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Text property removes everything but the text string. 
For text range, can you please provide sample input and output?